# Showing a statement of First-Order Logic is neither a validity nor a contradiction.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 267, exercise A. 2), asks:

Show that each of the following is neither a validity nor a
contradiction:

$\exists x T(x,h)$

**Refute validity**:

I am going to choose this interpretation:

Domain: cats, ants

$T(x,y)$: x is heavier than y.

h: cats,
a: ants

No element $d$ belonging to the domain satisfies $T(b,h)$ in interpretation $\mathbf{I}[b \setminus d]$ because

$T(h,h)$ is false, and $T(a,h)$ is false.

Is this proof correct ?

Comment: I assume that $h$ is an individual constant; if so, the formula means "there is something (in the domain) that is heavier that $h$".

Comment: Is $h$ an individual constant? In that case, $h$ refers to a specific cat, not all cats in the domain, unless in the domain there is only one cat.

Comment: Sorry to both of you, I should edit the answer to reflect that is was my option to choose that interpretation.

Comment: If you find an interpretation with respect to which $T$ is false and one with repect to which $T$ is true , you are done.

Comment: Review the def of *Interpretation* (in my edition **Ch.27.5**): "three things:
• the specification of a domain; • for each name that we care to consider, an assignment of exactly one object within the domain; • for each predicate ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there's a bit of confusion here - you seem to be interpreting $h$ as a *set* *(namely, of all cats)*. However, you have the right idea: consider a domain consisting of one cat *(who we name "$h$")* and one ant *(to whom we don't even give a specific name, nobody names ants)*, and interpret $T$ as "is heavier than." Then:

- $h$ is not heavier than itself.
- The only other element of our universe - the sadly-nameless ant - is not heavier than $h$.

So in this context, $\exists x(T(x,h))$ is indeed false. **But note the shift from *sets* to *individuals*.**

*(Actually, we didn't even need an ant at all - just consider the domain consisting of a single cat, which isn't heavier than itself. Ants are really unnecessary in general, too.)*

---

For showing that $\exists x(T(x,h))$ isn't a contradiction either, a similar idea should be employed - in fact, there's a couple ways to very slightly tweak the ideas above to get an answer here.

(It's separately worth giving *purely mathematical* example models: e.g. to show that $\exists x(T(x,y))$ is not valid, we could always work with the set $\{0\}$ and interpret $T$ as "is less than.")

Comment: Thank you very much! One question: to refute contradiction in this specific case; I need to show every element of the domain satisfies T? If so, I can offer: domain: {0, 1}, $T$ is greater than or equal to, and naming $h$ to be 0. We see 0 is greater than or equal to $g$ and, 1 is greater than or equal to $h$. Is this correct ?

Comment: @F.Zer "I need to show every element of the domain satisfies T" No, that's sufficient but not necessary. All you need is that *something* in the domain be $T$-related to the specific thing $h$. For example, taking $T$ to be equality would work (just set $x=h$). Your example also works, but is overkill: we could also have the domain be $\{0,1\}$, interpret $T$ as "greater than or equal to," and set $h=1$.